# SQL Query (Sybase): Subtract 1 from the sum of one column depending on the value of another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I have 2 SQL queries that I need to combine into one due to the sheer size of the database (most of the retail store locations, it is fine, but some have much much more transactions)

Basically, I need the number of transactions per employee for a given day. To do this, I am counting the distinct number of transaction numbers per employee (each item in a transaction gets its own row with the same transaction number, thus it needs to be distinct). However, there is a column "txnvoidmod". Basically the goal is that if the value of this column is 0, I simply count the transactions normally, but if the value is 1, I need to subtract off one because the transaction was actually voided.

Here is some sample data

```
+------ -+------------+-------------+
|transnum| txnvoidmod | salesprsnid |
+--------+------------+-------------+
| 115568 | 0          | 1339        |
| 115568 | 0          | 1339        |
| 114566 | 0          | 1339        |
| 114566 | 0          | 1339        |
| 115504 | 0          | 2555        |
| 105551 | 0          | 0452        |
| 105551 | 0          | 0452        |
| 105551 | 0          | 0452        |
| 105552 | 1          | 0452        |
| 105552 | 1          | 0452        |
| 105552 | 1          | 0452        |
+--------+------------+-------------+
```

I am omitting some fields that are unnecessary for this example.

Here is the query that I am using

```
 select txn_pos_transactions.cashiernum as salesprsnid, 
    (count(distinct MS.transnum))as transcnt
    from Txn_Merchandise_Sale MS  
    INNER JOIN txn_pos_transactions ON MS.transnum=txn_pos_transactions.transnum 
    Where MS.modtime like '2013-06-01 %' AND MS.itemdatetime like '2013-06-01 %' 
    and (txnvoidmod=0 or txnvoidmod=1) 
    Group by txn_pos_transactions.cashiernum order by salesprsnid
```

I am leaving out the fact that this query also is querying for netsales and units sold, so I must take that into account. Some sample results for this query (including the omitted netsales and units portion which is quite verbose)

```
+------ -+------------+-------------+-------------+
|transcnt| unitssold  | salesprsnid | netsalesamt |
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2      | 5          | 1339        | 98.50       |
| 1      | 2          | 2555        | 35.20       |
| 2      | 1          | 0452        | 24.00       |
+--------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

From above, the employee with id "0452" has 2 transaction in the results (transcnt), however, I need to build my query so that it actually reads as 0 transactions because their 1 transaction has a txnvoidmod equal to 1 and is actually a void of the previous transaction where txnvoidmod=0. If I only said "txnvoidmod=0" in the where clause, then "0452" would have 1 transaction, but I still need to subtract off the transaction where the txnvoidmod=1

I've tried various things such as conditionals and subtracting off the value of the txnvoidmod, but to no avail as it trys to group by the txnvoidmod which gives me unnecessary rows. I need there to be only one row per salesprsnid.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

By the way, I am using a SAP Sybase database.. it seems like for the most part that the queries are the same with the exception of a few items they are missing.

Comment: why do you have `or txnvoidmod=1` in the where clause?  Don't you want to exclude those records?

Comment: I just realized I worded my question slightly wrong. Not only do I need to NOT count them, I need to subtract one off when the txnvoidmod=1. The reason is because there is a corresponding transaction where the txnvoidmod=0, then when the transaction is voided, it comes in as another transaction where txnvoidmod=1. So I must only count the distinct transactions when txnvoidmod=0, then subtract 1 for every transaction where txnvoidmod equals 1. I edited the original post to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  txn_pos_transactions.cashiernum AS salesprsnid
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE txnvoidmod WHEN 1 THEN MS.transnum END) AS transcnt
FROM Txn_Merchandise_Sale MS  
  INNER JOIN txn_pos_transactions ON MS.transnum = txn_pos_transactions.transnum 
WHERE MS.modtime LIKE '2013-06-01 %' 
  AND MS.itemdatetime LIKE '2013-06-01 %' 
  AND txnvoidmod IN(0, 1) 
GROUP BY txn_pos_transactions.cashiernum 
ORDER BY salesprsnid
```

Comment: The above counts the number of transactions that are voided. However It gave me an idea that should work. I add COUNT(DISTINCT CASE txnvoidmod WHEN 1 THEN MS.transnum END) AS transvoids and then  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE txnvoidmod WHEN 0 THEN MS.transnum END) AS transcnt and simply subtract them in the logic. This should work.. However I get the following sql error "Null value eliminated in aggregate function". But it still works.. hmm, I will play around with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting an idea from Dave Sexton's comment, I changed my query to as follows:

```
 set ansinull off
 select txn_pos_transactions.cashiernum as salesprsnid, 
    (count((DISTINCT CASE txnvoidmod WHEN 0 THEN MS.transnum END)) - 
    (count((DISTINCT CASE txnvoidmod WHEN 1 THEN MS.transnum END)) as transcnt,
    from Txn_Merchandise_Sale MS  
    INNER JOIN txn_pos_transactions ON MS.transnum=txn_pos_transactions.transnum 
    Where MS.modtime like '2013-06-01 %' AND MS.itemdatetime like '2013-06-01 %' 
    and (txnvoidmod=0 or txnvoidmod=1) 
    Group by txn_pos_transactions.cashiernum order by salesprsnid
```

I had to include "set ansinull off" because I was getting null aggregate errors. Not sure if this will slow me down or not, but this does appear to work.

Thanks